# How is Arc implemented? How is it only 8 bytes large?

Tags: rust, memory

I noticed that the size of `Arc` is only 8 bytes in Rust. What is the basic implementation for `Arc`? My sense is that it would require at least a pointer and counter, and the pointer alone would be 8 bytes already. Is it the same for `Rc`?

Answer (score 11):

As with any implementation question, the answer may be out-of-date in a future version.

**tl;dr** the count can't be part of the `Arc`, because everyone with a reference has their own instance of the `Arc` struct. The count has to be somewhere shared.

In the current standard library implementation, `Arc<T>` is defined as

```
pub struct Arc<
    T: ?Sized,
    #[unstable(feature = "allocator_api", issue = "32838")] A: Allocator = Global,
> {
    ptr: NonNull<ArcInner<T>>,
    phantom: PhantomData<ArcInner<T>>,
    alloc: A,
}
```

This is three things: a pointer to an `ArcInner<T>`, a zero-sized [phantom](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/phantom-data.html) used for static analysis regarding variance and related matters, and an allocator. By default, this uses the global allocator (a zero-sized struct that says to use the system malloc/free or equivalent).

In that typical case where you don't bring your own allocator, an `Arc<T>` object's bytes is simply a pointer to the `ArcInner`, which is defined as follows:

```
#[repr(C)]
struct ArcInner<T: ?Sized> {
    strong: atomic::AtomicUsize,

    // the value usize::MAX acts as a sentinel for temporarily "locking" the
    // ability to upgrade weak pointers or downgrade strong ones; this is used
    // to avoid races in `make_mut` and `get_mut`.
    weak: atomic::AtomicUsize,

    data: T,
}
```

[source](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/src/alloc/sync.rs.html#349-359)

It's this ArcInner that holds the counts and the data being shared through the Arc.

Note that the count is stored alongside the data itself. This makes sense - *the count needs to be shared between all `Arc`s that are pointing to the same data, rather than each Arc having its own counter*. If each Arc had its own counter, there would be no way to agree on what the reference count ought to be at any moment. Instead, as individual `Arc` objects are created by cloning and dropped, this one shared reference count tracks how many of these Arc objects are out there.

It's worth noting that an `Arc` may not always be sized 8 bytes on a 64-bit system. For a 64-bit system, 8 bytes is enough for a *thin* pointer (i.e. just an address, with no additional metadata).

However, Rust has something called *fat pointers* which arise in cases where an address is not enough to define an object. A common case of a fat pointer is a pointer or reference to a [dynamically sized type](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/exotic-sizes.html#dynamically-sized-types-dsts), such as a slice where the length isn't statically specified. e.g. `&[u8]` but not `&[u8; 4096]`. Other examples of DSTs are trait objects (i.e. adorned with `dyn`); `&dyn` references are likewise fat pointers, with the metadata pointing to the vtable that lets the caller find the correct implementation of the trait's methods.

Recall the `T: ?Sized` bound in `Arc` and `ArcInner`? By default, generic type parameters aren't allowed to be DSTs, since DSTs are very restrictive (they cannot be put onto the stack, returned by value, etc). This weird-looking bound allows T, the type parameter, to be a DST - and consequently, `ArcInner` to become a DST if `T` is a DST.

If your ArcInner is a DST, then the `NotNull<ArcInner<T>>` itself will store a fat pointer instead, and the `Arc` will store a fat pointer + two zero-sized types. For example, on x86_64, all of the following will actually be 16 bytes:

- `Arc<str>` - an Arc holding a string slice. Needs space to store the address of the ArcInner and the metadata about the size of the `data` field.
- `Arc<[u8]>` - an Arc holding an array of u8 of unknown length. Likewise.
- `Arc<dyn Foo>`, where `Foo` is an object-safe trait. Needs to store the address of the ArcInner and a vtable that allows a caller to locate the correct implementation of functions in `Foo`.
- An Arc holding my own struct that's a DST (either because I put a DST in the last field, or the last field was generic and I allowed a DST there using `T: ?Sized`)

By the way, Rc is very similar - although instead of an ArcInner with atomic refcounts, it [has an RcBox that has `Cell<usize>` refcounts](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/src/alloc/rc.rs.html#288-292).